# rotate a matrix using different angles

Tags: java, math, matrix

I searched on internet and I saw lots of posts about how to rotate a matrix or an image by 90 or 180 degrees.But how can I rotate a matrix with 12 degrees or 162 degrees?
From:
[image]

To:

[image]

This image is rotated with ~35 degrees.

As you can see my matrix is the horse image and the circle is the rotation path, and the big rectangle is the new matrix created after rotation.

How can i achieve this? Thanks!

PS: This does not work

```
int angle=35*Math.PI/180;
int x1 = (int)(x * cos(angle)) - (y * sin(angle));
int y1 = (int)(y * cos(angle)) + (x * sin(angle));
```

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: java.I just want to rotate a matrix for a graphic engine using pixels

Comment: I'd say your second example image is rotated -35 degrees, or 325 degrees (positive rotation is typically counter clockwise). Also, your variable name is a bit misleading now, i'd call it "angle" or "radians" since it now is representing an angle expressed in radians.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your code would work if you saved *x* value before using it to compute *y*.

- *deg* should be in **[radian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)** not in degrees: `35*PI/180`
- you shouldn't compute with integers since *cos* and *sin* are between [0,1], think about floats.

---

```
float angle = 35*Math.PI/180;
int x1 = round(x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle));
int y1 = round(y * cos(angle) + x * sin(angle));
```

Note: casting is huggly.

Comment: I updated the post.Anyway this still doesn't work.I'm getting -1 for x1 or y1

Comment: But you didn't update your angle with [radian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) !

Comment: I cant' use floats because my matrix is using integers as indices

Comment: Yes you can use float while computing and then get a rounded value for your matrix (even angle should be a float).

Comment: Hmmm.Can you post a full code with all the for loops?For example use a 3X3 matrix with {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}} and rotate it 35 degrees.Look what I found  (http://polymathprogrammer.com/2008/10/06/image-rotation-with-bilinear-interpolation/)